# Is it possible to create sub-node that can assign on a node?

Tags: nodes, 7

The idea is to create a chapter(sub-node) that can assign on a book(node:page). I know this can be done with taxonomy, but I dont wanna have 1000+ of taxonomy on my site. Is it possible, if so, how?

Comment: Are you using Drupal 7?

Comment: yes, its a Drupal 7 site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want a Book that has chapters and you want them linked like a book? There is a module for that in Core called book. https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/book

Comment: I didnt even know Drupal has such feature on default module. TY